# how to clear global var between tests in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I have 2 tests which each one them pass but when i run them together the second test fails.
I have this global var (CURR_GUID) which i want to clear between the tests but i am not sure how to do that.
Since it is not cleared between the tests , its value is still "1111111" and not null.

Any idea?

**Class W**

```
"use strict";

var CURR_GUID = null;

class W {
    constructor() {
        console.log("W ctor")
    }

    async getDataFromDb() {
        if (CURR_GUID) {
            return CURR_GUID;
        } else {
            this.db = require("./Connection").getDb();
            console.log("W getDataFromDb")
            let res = null;
            res = await this.db.one("SELECT guid FROM table", ["NONE"]);
            return res.guid;
        }
    }

    async saveGuid(guid) {
        this.db = require("./Connection").getDb();
        await this.db.none("update table set guid=$1", [guid]);
        CURR_GUID = guid;
        console.log("currr is" + CURR_GUID);
    }
}

module.exports = W;
```

**Class X**

```
"use strict";

const wDao = new (require("../db/W"))();

class X {
    async getGuid() {
        console.log("X getGuid")
        let guid = await wDao.getDataFromDb();
        console.log("got guid " + guid);

        await wDao.saveGuid(guid);
        return guid;
    }
}

module.exports = X;
```

**Test.spec.js**

```
const chai = require("chai");
const expect = chai.expect;
const X = require("../src/service/X");
const Connection = require("../src/db/Connection");
const sinon = require("sinon");

describe("component_test", function () {
    afterEach(function () {
        this.dbStub.restore();
    });

    it("X_component_test", async function () {
        var db = {
            one: async () => {
                return {
                    guid: '1111111',
                    created_on: "123"
                }
            },
            none: async () => {
            }
        };
        this.dbStub = sinon.stub(Connection, "getDb").returns(db);

        var dao = new X();
        var guid = await dao.getGuid();
        expect(guid).to.equal('1111111');
    });

    it("X_component_test_2", async function () {
        var db = {
            one: async () => {
                return {
                    guid: '222222',
                    created_on: "123"
                }
            },
            none: async () => {
            }
        };
        this.dbStub = sinon.stub(Connection, "getDb").returns(db);

        var dao = new X();
        var guid = await dao.getGuid();
        expect(guid).to.equal('222222');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

While it should be possible to achieve the desired result by deleting W and X modules from [require.cache](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_cache) in `afterEach` hook, it might be better to modify the source code a bit so that it can be tested without cache manipulations.

*Class W*

Turn `CURR_GUID` variable into an instance property.

```
"use strict";
   
class W {
    constructor() {
        console.log("W ctor");
        this.CURR_GUID = null;
    }

    async getDataFromDb() {
        if (this.CURR_GUID) {
            return this.CURR_GUID;
        } else {
            this.db = require("./Connection").getDb();
            console.log("W getDataFromDb")
            let res = null;
            res = await this.db.one("SELECT guid FROM table", ["NONE"]);
            return res.guid;
        }
    }

    async saveGuid(guid) {
        this.db = require("./Connection").getDb();
        await this.db.none("update table set guid=$1", [guid]);
        this.CURR_GUID = guid;
        console.log("currr is" + this.CURR_GUID);
    }
}

module.exports = W;
```

*Class X*

Turn `wDao` from variable into an instance property

```
"use strict";

const WDao = require("../db/W");

class X {
    constructor() {
        this.wDao = new WDao();
    } 

    async getGuid() {
        console.log("X getGuid")
        let guid = await this.wDao.getDataFromDb();
        console.log("got guid " + guid);

        await this.wDao.saveGuid(guid);
        return guid;
    }
}

module.exports = X;
```

In this way every test should work with fresh instances of W and X that do not depend on the closure state.